How to play wistia video in React native expo project (already installed expo-av video n not working)?
I want to play wistia video in react native project
I'd tried using expo-av Video but its giving me error
com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (FlvExtractor, FlacExtractor, WavExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, AmrExtractor, PsExtractor, OggExtractor, TsExtractor, MatroskaExtractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, Ac4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AviExtractor, JpegExtractor) could read the stream.

is there any library player for expo project to run wistia videos in it?
example wistia link is like this - https://alcatrazz-627.wistia.com/medias/{videoId}
